# Restricting Page Header to Second Page in Report Output in Cognos

Tags: cognos

My report consists of 3 pages(titel, report and anhang) and report page is quite long, so it can be longer than 1 page. I want to restrict created header only to the second page. How can I do it in Cognos analytics report studio(version 11)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Condition Explorer.
2. Create a new Boolean Variable with this expression: `PageNumber() = 2`
3. Make sure all of the page header features you want hidden on page 1 are in a block.
4. Set the *Render variable* property of the block to the boolean variable you just created.